# Python + PyODBC + SQL Server Temp Table + OPENROWSET on Excel File - Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for linked server (null) reported an error

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, openrowset

I am trying to use Python and SQL Server OPENROWSET to import data from an Excel file into a SQL Server temp table. The following code works fine if I import the data into a permanent table using OPENROWSET, but I receive the following SQL Server error when attempting to insert into a temp table. I want to be able to do this with temp tables on servers for which I don't have access to create permanent tables. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
> Server]The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
> server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any
> information about the error. (7399) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000]
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot
> initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". (7303)')

- Python 3.7
- PyODBC is up to date
- SQL Server 2019

```
cnx = pyodbc.connect      (
                            "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                            "SERVER=SERVERNAME;"
                            "Database=master;"
                            "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                             "cnx.autocommit = True;"
                            )

cursor1 = cnx.cursor()
query1 = ('''set nocount on;''')
query2 = ('''if object_id ('tempdb..##TABLE1') is not null drop table ##TABLE1;''')
query3 = ('''
            select
            cast([Column1] as bigint) Column_1
            ,cast([Column2] as varchar(255)) Column_2
            --etc for all columns in excel file
            into ##TABLE1
            FROM OPENROWSET(
            'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
            'Excel 12.0 Xml;
            HDR=YES;
            IMEX=1;
            Database=F:\Filename.xlsx', 
            [sheetname$]);
            ''')
try:
    cursor1.execute(query1)
    cursor1.execute(query2)
    cursor1.execute(query3)
except Exception as e2:
     print(e2)
finally:
cursor1.close()
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you do first `CREATE TABLE ##Table1 (...cols...)` then `INSERT ##Table1 (...cols....) SELECT ... FROM OPENROWSET ...` And does the same issue happen if you try from SSMS?

Comment: Error numbers 7399 and 7303 suggest other problems than using a ##temp table. Ref: [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database # Common Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql#common-errors). Does `F:\Filename.xlsx` exist on the SQL Server itself, or only on your local computer? Does the account under which the SQL Server service executes have file system ACLs granting it access to the file and folder? Are all copies of Excel using the file closed?